# What is the elegant way of for loop with condition to add to a list in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

What is the more elegant way of doing the following code in Kotlin

```
fun bar(bars:List<Bar>): List<Foo>{
  val foos = mutableListOf<Foo>()
  for(bar in bars){
    val foo = foo(bar)
    if(foo != null){
      foos.add(foo)
    }
  }
  return foos
}

fun foo(bar:Bar): Foo?{
  if(bar.something){
    return null
  }
  return Foo()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`bar()` can be rewritten to use [`mapNotNull()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-not-null.html):

```
fun bar(bars: List<Bar>) = bars.mapNotNull{ foo(it) }
```

or (using a method reference):

```
fun bar(bars: List<Bar>) = bars.mapNotNull(::foo)
```

And `foo()` could also be written with an expression body:

```
fun foo(bar: Bar) = if (bar.something) null else Foo()
```

(I've omitted the return types too, as the compiler easily infers them — though you may want to keep them for extra safety/readability.)

Both would also work well as extension functions:

```
fun List<Bar>.bar() = mapNotNull{ it.foo() }

fun Bar.foo() = if (something) null else Foo()
```

Comment: You don't need to use `null` here at all, just filter on `Bar.something`. Added an answer.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip I was interpreting the question as wanting to keep both functions.  Of course, if you don't need to keep `foo()`, you can do the whole thing in one line.

Comment: Right. It's hard to tell when a "more elegant way of doing the following code" is all we have to go on 

Answer (score 2):

The whole thing can be simplified to:

```
bars.filterNot { it.something }.map { Foo() }
```

This is because you are doing two things:

1. `foo` returns `Foo()` if a certain property is false, otherwise returns null
2. `bar` filters out the non-null results.

So what you want are `Foo` objects for every bar where `Bar.something` is false, which is what this does.

---

Working example:

```
class Foo
data class Bar(val something: Boolean)

fun List<Bar>.toFoos(): List<Foo> = filterNot { it.something }.map { Foo() }

fun main() {
    val input = listOf(Bar(true), Bar(false), Bar(false),  Bar(true), Bar(true))
    val output = input.toFoos()
    println(output)
}
```

Output;

```
[Foo@4a574795, Foo@f6f4d33]
```

Comment: Using `filterNot()` is simpler and makes the intent clearer — but it does create a third copy of the list, so is a little less efficient.  (Swings, roundabouts…)

Comment: It makes an intermediate list, but it doesn't copy the elements inside the list, so it's a small price to pay. Smaller than the cost of debugging a `NullPointerException` later.

Comment: You don't need to worry about NullPointerExceptions anyway as long as you don't use `!!`. The fact that you no longer need to fear null values is half the reason Kotlin exists.

Comment: That's only true if you're dealing with pure-Kotlin code. As soon as you have platform types, you could get an NPE at any time. But that's not relevant to this example, so fair point. I still think filter then map is clearer and more intentional than `mapNotNull { convertOrNull(it) }`.

Comment: It feels like an anti-pattern to use `null` for program flow.

Answer (score 0):

U could use `mapNotNull()`.

```kotlin
val foos = bars.mapNotNull { foo(it) }
```

Hope its elegant enough.

Answer (score 0):

These two functions could be replaced with the following one-liner:

```kotlin
fun bar(bars:List<Bar>): List<Foo> = Array(bars.count { !it.something }) { Foo() }.asList()
```

Answer (score 0):

the elegent way is to write it in a functional way :

```
 fun bar(bars: List<Bar>): List<Foo> {
     return bars.filter { !it.something }.map { Foo() }
 }
```

Comment: `filterNot { it.something }`